# Bootstrap Resampling: Different results with different input structures

Tags: r, statistics, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

It seems supplying a list vs. a dataframe to a bootstrap resampling function in R can produce different results.

```r
library(dplyr)

ctrl <- iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species == 'virginica')
ctrl <- ctrl$Sepal.Length
      
test <- iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species == 'setosa')
test <- test$Sepal.Length

input_list1 <- data.frame(control=ctrl, test=test)
input_list2 <- list(control=ctrl, test=test)


mean_d <- function(data, indices) {
  control <- data$control[indices]
  test <- data$test[indices]

  return(mean(test) - mean(control))
}



set.seed(12345)
boot_result1 <- boot::boot(input_list1,
                           mean_d,
                           R = 5000)
set.seed(NULL)


set.seed(12345)
boot_result2 <- boot::boot(input_list2,
                           mean_d,
                           R = 5000)
```

The true mean difference between `virginica` and `setosa` sepal lengths, is of course

```sh
> mean(test) - mean(control)
```

```
[1] - 1.582
```

Only `boot_result1`, which received a data.frame, produces the correct result:

```sh
> boot_result1
```

```
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot::boot(data = input_list2, statistic = mean_d, R = 5000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original    bias    std. error
t1*   -1.582 -0.000972  0.09649542
```

`boot_result2`, which received a list as input, produces an inaccurate mean difference.

```sh
> boot_result2
```

```
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot::boot(data = input_list1, statistic = mean_d, R = 5000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original  bias    std. error
t1*    -1.05  -3e-05    0.106013
```

Why would this be the case?

Comment: The help says *The data as a vector, matrix or data frame.* & a very quick glance at the `boot` code show `n <- NROW(data)` which will be an issue for your list. So don't use lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the vignette of boot() :

> In all other cases ‘statistic’ must take at least two arguments.  The
> first argument passed will always be the original data.  The second
> will be a vector of indices, frequencies or weights which define the
> bootstrap sample.

In your example, the list is of length two, so it will sample 1:2, and this will be your indices. If you look at your t0, it is the difference between your first 2 entries in each list:

```
mean(c(6.3,5.8))-mean(c(5.1,4.9))
[1] 1.05
```

To write this using a list, do:

```
mean_d <- function(data, indices) {
  control <- sapply(data[indices],"[[","control")
  test <- sapply(data[indices],"[[","test")

  return(mean(test) - mean(control))
}

input_list2 <- asplit(data.frame(control=ctrl, test=test),1)

set.seed(12345)
boot_result2 <- boot::boot(input_list2,
                           mean_d,
                           R = 5000)

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot::boot(data = input_list2, statistic = mean_d, R = 5000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original    bias    std. error
t1*   -1.582 -0.000972  0.09649542
```

I think it's a bit more complicated than should be. Maybe you need to use it for some other data. Essentially your list needs to be structured such that every element is the data point to bootstrap.